# Should I break process and deliver to customer, or vice versa?

Tags: software-industry, projects, customer-relation

I am in a tough situation that keeps coming up over and over again and it's stressful to deal with each time.

So I work for department A, A is not a well defined or structured department (we do BA, Coding, Consulting, Pre-Sales, Client Relations, Support). This department has a very low employee count, because good luck finding someone that is well versed in all these different skill levels.

We have a weird setup in our office - we have 2 products (BB and CC) where department B (R&D) develops and maintains these applications. However the lowest layers of code are maintained by us (Department A) because we integrate out to third party services. Department B is agile, and answers to product management, Department A is not part of any of Department Bs process (we do not answer to any product manager). Department A also doesn't have access to same repository or ability to make commits in version control, even though we make changes to the lowest layers of code. (This is something I am currently discussing with having them change).

I am one of the more senior people on this department. I am currently working on multiple projects with very tight deadlines. It's difficult for us to make commitments to client when something will be done, because if it involves Department B, they are on their own schedule and timelines and they do not answer to customer projects.

I have had to on multiple occasions, make changes to the core product code (a layer we shouldn't touch) to make deadlines meet in my projects. This gets in trouble with Department B because I am breaking process and causing them problems. However if I did not do this, we would have to explain why we couldn't deliver to the client (again).

What really sucks is that our department gets blamed for project slowness / missed deadlines, because the customer only interacts with our department, and other departments don't have to take responsibility for a product that doesn't work in the 'live' environment.

What should I do in this situation? If I continue following process, other departments like sales, and the VPs of my department will look to me as to why we couldn't deliver this project to client. If I break process, I upset department B, but I keep my end of the bargain to customer intact and my bosses happy. It seems like a lose-lose situation, it's bad enough the work is stressful, but any move I make will come back to bite me in a negative way.

Updating this question to mention - this has been escalated and communicated to my manager and other managers / executives involved. So all the parties are aware there is an issue, but no clear directive yet as to what to do.

Comment: Escalate? Why haven't you raised this with your manager(s) yet?

Comment: My manager is aware, but he has no idea what to do about it (I think there is a bit of a power struggle between him and the manager of dept B)

Comment: Going around the process is never the correct fix.

Comment: @Igneous01 - Sounds like you need to delegate your customer relations to your manager when the project is late because of Dept B

Comment: Well if I don't, then it's my fault that we couldn't deliver project. So do I just accept responsibility for something outside of my control?

Comment: @Igneous01 Correction: it's your manager's fault. There's little you can do in this scenario beyond implementing CYA tactis.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Stop breaking protocol.  It keeps your bosses happy *for now* because they don't care what you do as long as you get it done.  *Eventually* this will come back to bite you in the ass, and you'll be left on the defensive to explain why you've been breaking protocol on a semi-regular basis.

**Step 2:** Raise your concerns with your immediate superiors.  Set a meeting if necessary, to explain the problem in as much detail as you think they can comprehend (going deep into technical detail with non-technical supervisors rarely works out well.)  It would help at this stage if you could document how many times a week/month this becomes an issue.  Make it clear that this is a problem because **clients are unhappy**.

**Step 3:** Ask your superiors what can be done to alleviate the problem.  Put new processes in place, establish some means of communication between dept A and dept B to facilitate these changes, etc.  Get the ball rolling on a more permanent and official solution.

If your superiors are unwilling to listen or to do anything, then just do your best *without circumventing protocol* and wait for the *client feedback* to make this an issue they can't ignore.  Document everything in this situation, to ensure you have the evidence to back up your claims that this is an issue (and more specifically, an issue *you've told them about*) when they do come around.

Comment: My manager is aware (in fact all of the superiors I work with are aware) but there are some internal politics that is preventing changes from being implemented.

Comment: For the second option, I have lots and lots of emails, but they are scattered everywhere. (I get on average 60 emails a day) so for me to track down every last piece of documentation can easily take a few hours, which is time I do not have. The other communications are through slack (but our company is using free version, so old history is lost).

Comment: And don;t commit to client deadlines without checking with the people who are supposed to do the work according to the process.  As for the emails, I get hundreds day, you set up folders to put the relevant ones in. And if appropriate you set up rules to filter them into the folders or do it yourself at the time you read the email.

Comment: Deadlines we have no control over - sales is pushing the deadline, and we are pushing back against sales because the deadlines are not reasonable. But i have to work with the parameters that are given to me on a project ( as well as fight back when timelines are unreasonable ). However I will take your advice and dedicate an hour or 2 sorting out my inbox because it's definitely a mess.